# Node - Throw SOAP error on an promise catch block

Tags: node.js, soap, promise, throw, pg-promise

I am developing an **SOAP Server in NodeJ**S (v6.9.4) using the **[SOAP](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap)** library. I have to request some data from a Postgres database. I choose to use the **[pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)** lib.

SAOP Services are implemented like this :

```
TestConnection: function (args, cb, headers, req) {
db.any("select * from users where active=$1", [true])
  .then(function (data) {
    return {};
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    throw {
      Fault: {
        faultcode: faultCode,
        faultstring: faultString,
        detail: {
          "ns:FaultInformation": {
            "ns:FaultCode": detailedFaultCode,
            "ns:FaultText": detailedFaultText
          }
        },
        statusCode: 500
      }
    };
  });
}
```

In case of error during the database connection/request, I need to return a SOAP Fault. On the SOAP lib, you can do this by [throwing a new Fault object](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#soap-fault).

In this example, I want to throw it in the catch block. I know it's not the right way to do this and I am facing this issue :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 3): [object Object]

How can I throw my **SOAP Fault exception in the main service function**. I tried without success the setTimeout solution. Is the promise a good solution for PG queries ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself by using the **soap callback function** (cb) provided by the soap lib. The following code should return a Soap Fault exception under an Async service implementation :

```
TestConnection: function (args, cb, headers, req) {
db.any("select * from users where active=$1", [true])
  .then(function (data) {
    cb({});
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    cb({
      Fault: {
        faultcode: faultCode,
        faultstring: faultString,
        detail: {
          "ns:FaultInformation": {
            "ns:FaultCode": detailedFaultCode,
            "ns:FaultText": detailedFaultText
          }
        },
        statusCode: 500
      }
    });
  });
 }
```